# Upload File/Image Using Retrofit MultiPart Entity is Encrypted?

Tags: android, encryption, retrofit, okhttp

I'm uploading a file on server using multipart entity, in logcat shows Unicode characters like this

```
�S��!1aAQq"23����������?���@�������]�4�~E��zR=D�HW��z��E��6LŊV5�rl�7EOP�|�h��w5�Rx
```

Is the file has been encrypted or obfuscated?

Thanks in advance

Comment: If it is a plain txt file it is.

Comment: @blackapps is it a data file?

Answer (score 1):

it's normal that whatever file you send via multipart, logcat shows it as Unicode characters. your file is not encrypted or obfuscated.

Comment: thanks for the response, so why logcat show it as Unicode characters?